# Can I install `caret` on CentOS?

Tags: r, centos, r-caret, r-package

I am running the latest version of RServer on a CentOS EC2 instance.

I'd like to install `caret`, but I am getting this error message.

```
install.packages("caret", dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

> Installing package into
>   ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4’ (as ‘lib’ is
>   unspecified) Warning in install.packages :   package ‘caret’ is not
>   available (for R version 3.4.1)

I saw that the [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) has OS and Windows binaries, but not Linux.

I looked into installing a Microsoft Server EC2 machine instead, but it looks like RServer is not supported. Can I install `caret` on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that binary packages are only available for Windows and Mac. Linux systems are just to diverse. However, on the CRAN page you linked you can also see

```
Depends: R (>= 3.5.0)
```

You have to update your R installation. After that there should be no problems installing the package on Linux.

Comment: Linux systems aren’t all that diverse. By precompiling one binary for CentOS and another for Ubuntu you cover ~99% of the desktop/server market, and that is in fact what many commercial software vendors do. With care you can reduce even this to a single, statically linked binary (but making the result efficient is a pain).